# Prevent if-statement if last removed letter after a word is a whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
  if (/^([a-z\d] ?)+[a-z\d]$/i.test(this.value)) {
    alert('True');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' value='Ended with Space '>
```

In my Script here, If you pressed `backspace` to remove the whitespace  in it the if-statement triggeres, I want to prevent that from happening, How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input').keyup(function (evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode === 8) return;
  if (/^([a-z\d] ?)+[a-z\d]$/i.test(this.value)) {
    alert('True');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' value='Ended with Space '>
```

Note that `.keyCode` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), but will probably still work in most browsers. MDN currently recommends use of [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) where implemented, but browser support is still partly lacking at the time of writing.

Here's an example using `.code`:

```js
$('input').keyup(function (evt) {
  if (evt.originalEvent.code === 'Backspace') return
  if (/^([a-z\d] ?)+[a-z\d]$/i.test(this.value)) {
    alert('True');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' value='Ended with Space '>
```

Interestingly, jQuery (in the above version at least) does not expose `code` on the event object, so you have to access it via `originalEvent`.

Finally, for completeness compare the behaviour of the `keypress` event (per note in comments):

```js
$('input').keypress(function (evt) {
  if (/^([a-z\d] ?)+[a-z\d]$/i.test(this.value)) {
    alert('True');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' value='Ended with Space '>
```

Comment: should i use `.which`, also i tried to prevent `keyCode == 8` But i want to alert If the form is valid to the RegEx which it is.

Comment: I think if something is deprecated you should give an example that's valid.

Comment: @Matheo Yes because it is normalized BUT better would be to use `keypress` event which doesn't fire for backspace

Comment: That's fair, although `keyCode` is so widely used it's near-ubiquitous. However, I'll link to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and explain further. Cheers!